# Spring. Cannot load driver class: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, hsqldb, spring-jdbc

I am creating a simple app to experiment with the hsqldb database, but i cant even start because my IDE giving me an exeption

> "Cannot load driver class: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"

I've researched this problem, but i didnt find the solution.
I am using Sprint tool suit 4.4 as my IDE.

This is my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

This is my `pom.xml` (i have added more than i need, i thought that maybe the problem is "not enough dependencies"):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.32.3.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Derby DB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>${derby.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I also tried to change the version of hsqldb dependency but i didnt work.

This is my simple **dao** class:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Override
public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
    String query = "SELECT * from products";
    RowMapper<Product> rowMapper = new ProductRowMapper();
    List<Product> list = jdbcTemplate.query(query, rowMapper);
    return list;
}

@Override
public void addProduct(Product product) {
    String query = "INSERT INTO products(id, name) VALUES(?, ?)";
    jdbcTemplate.update(query, product.getId(), product.getName());

}

}
```

I also checked the class path of the driver, and it is in place. I cant imagine what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `<scope>test</scope>` from the dependency. You are not using the hsqldb for tests only.
Also, the `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver` is redundant, since the driver is part of the datasource url.

Comment: Specifying the `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` is not necessarily redundant. It is necessary for the driver to be loaded; JDBC automatic driver loading doesn't work in all situations.